# Fetch data from db to js array

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

So I'm creating a page that has a calendar and I want to display the events that I insert on a different page to the database

How can I display the events on the calendar ?

This is the js code that came with the template (I don't have a lot of js skills)

I think that the part where it displays the events is on the "events: [...]
but I don't know how to fetch the data from the database

```
var initCalendar = function() {
    var $calendar = $('#calendar');
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $calendar.fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            right: 'prev,today,next,basicDay,basicWeek,month'
        },

        timeFormat: 'h:mm',

        titleFormat: {
            month: 'MMMM YYYY',      // September 2009
            week: "MMM d YYYY",      // Sep 13 2009
            day: 'dddd, MMM d, YYYY' // Tuesday, Sep 8, 2009
        },

        themeButtonIcons: {
            prev: 'fa fa-caret-left',
            next: 'fa fa-caret-right',
        },
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: false,
                className: 'fc-event-danger'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                url: 'http://google.com/'
            }
        ]
    });
```

I haven't created the database table yet but I have an idea of how am I going to make it.

Comment: You should go through the PHP-MySQL database connectivity and understand CRUD operations later you have to check how to integrate javascript with PHP and HTML

Comment: Code suggestion ??? @MangeshSathe

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp check this tutorial

Comment: Mate I know php + mysql operations I just don't how to fetch the data to javascript array vars

Comment: if you know the DB operations the pull the necessary data from database. Key events : looks like its a JSON, so once you have data array ready from database, just use json_encode to get the proper format. Then using for the event key just integrate json encoded array to event like event : <?php $myJsonCalData; ?>

Comment: This tutorial you can refer for PHP JSON and javascript https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-json-data-with-php-or-javascript/

Comment: @MangeshSathe is there some way that we can talk private ?

Comment: yes, we can talk here. I could not find chat option in stackoverflow

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to talk on chat so , if I could do this in php I would do it like this `$sql = "select..."` and the I would to a while loop to fetch all the data that is on the database , but since that code that I've put in the post is in a .js file I can't write php code on it.. how am I going to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve this.

1. The best and simplest way is sending an **AJAX REQUEST** to your server side script. Your server side scripts query's the database, processes your data and returns a response to your ajax request. Consider doing this with `echo json_encode($array_values)` in `Php`. From there you can handle the response using javascript within your ajax request. You may need to parse your response like so `var result = JSON.parse(data)` in `javascript`.

For example:

```
//Within Your HTML Script
axios({
  method: 'POST', //you can set what request you want to be
  url: 'getdb.php',
  data: {id: 1},
})
.then(function (response) {
  // Server side response
  var result = JSON.parse(response.data);
  console.log(result );
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});

//getdb.php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$array_values = array();
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $array_values[] = $row;
};
echo json_encode($array_values)
$conn->close();
?>
```

2. Another way is when you are making server side calls with `Php` within your `HTML`. In which case:

```
    <script>
      var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("<?php echo json_encode($array_values)?>"));
    </script>
```

3. Finally, you can embed `HTML` within `Php` as well. Which will be:

```
    <?php
     echo "<script>var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('json_encode({$array_values})'))</script>"
    ?>
```

Your response from your serverside script would be something like this:

```
$array_values = array('header' => 
                           array('left' => 'title', 'right' => 'prev,today....'),
                      'timeFormat' => 'h:mm',
                      .....,
                      'events' => array(
                           array('title' => 'All Day', 'start' => 'Date...'),
                           array('title' => 'All Day', 'start' => 'Date...'),
                           array('title' => 'All Day', 'start' => 'Date...'),
                       )

                )
echo json_encode($array_values );
```

Then in your javascript you can do something like this:

```
var result = JSON.parse(response.data);
$calendar.fullCalendar(result);
```

**OR**

```
//independently change each property without affecting others
var result = JSON.parse(response.data);
$calendar.fullCalendar().header= result.header;
$calendar.fullCalendar().timeFormat= result.timeFormat;
$calendar.fullCalendar().events= result.events;

//$calendar.fullCalendar() function is simply accepting an object as a parameter
```

The reason why you can do this is because the javascript variable result now looks something like this after the **SERVER SIDE RESPONSE**:

```
result = {
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            right: 'prev,today,next,basicDay,basicWeek,month'
        },
        timeFormat: 'h:mm',
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            },
        }
```

Which obviously depends on how you structured you response from Php;

Comment: So if I go the first option how can I call that data to the code that I posted ?

Comment: updated. Don't forget to tick this if it was helpful

Comment: do you have discord or twitter ? so I can talk to you better, I'm a little confused..

Comment: In what area? And i'm not on twitter. Just IG. Read up a little on javascript objects. This `$calendar.fullCalendar()` is simply accepting an object as it's parameter

Comment: Let me see If I'm right.. I create a file called ajax.php (example) and I put the code that is in the first example and then I put the last code (javascript response) in the calendar.js (it's where is located the code from the post I created above)? I just don't see any reference linking both files

Comment: The `url` property of the axios function must be linked to the file that holds your server side code. Eg. `url: ajax.php`. Don't forget to upvote me too.

Comment: Please talk with me in a discord chat please, i'm more confused now (I already upvote you) https://discord.gg/NJgyNP

Comment: Just visit this link w3schools.com in an hours time you'd be alright

Answer (score 0):

use the jquery ajax function to fetch data.

```
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'abc.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                start: start.format(),
                end: end.format()
            },
            success: function(responce) {
                var events = responce.bookingData;
                callback(events);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: He wants to integrate db data to js events. only event key needs data from DB. Ajax call is not required in this case.